# jquery mobile doesn't implements styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have created a simple mobile web page, I don't no why but the button I have created doesn't stylized like in this [link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width ,  user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="themes/theme.min.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>

    <title>page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure, your local libraries are available and the paths are correct...
[see working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5pt6b/) with the newest libraries

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is with your stylesheet links. You need to include `rel="stylesheet"` instead of setting `type`.

E.g.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>`